# rendring t hello world with drink button and goodbye world with food button

Tags: reactjs, jsx

//hello the problem when i click drink it console hello world goodbye world togather  and when i click food it show hello world goobye world togather also

```
class Item extends React.Component {

  constructor()  {
    super();
    this.state = {
    Card1: 0
  } ;
  this.state = {
    Card2: 0
  };
}
  handleClick = (button) => {
   this.setState({ Card1: button })
  };
handel = (event) => {
  this.setState({ Card2: event })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

 <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}>drink</button>
 <button onClick={() => this.handel(1)}>food </button>
 <div>
{this.state.handel ? console.log("goodbye world") : console.log("null")}
{this.state.handleClick  ? console.log('hello world') : console.log("null")}
</div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow. 
Just a few fundamental errors.

There should be only 1 state variable in the constructor.

```
this.state = {
Card1: 0,
Card2: 0,
};
```

In your render you should be checking the state variable and then printing to console.You are string to check something which is undefined.

```
{this.state.Card2 ? console.log("goodbye world") : console.log("null")}
{this.state.Card1 ? console.log('hello world') : console.log("null")}
```

let me know if this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues in your code.

> In your code state initialization is not correct which is out side
>   constructor. You no need to declare state initialization two times in
>   one component.
>
> Event handlers are not correct.
>
> you are setting state to card1 and card2 but you are checking handler
>   function like this.state.handle which is not correct.
>
> Play with boolean values than using 0 and 1 in your case.
>
> Have meaning
>   full names for state and handler function as per buttons

You should do something like below.

```
class Item extends React.Component {

  constructor()  {
    super();
    this.state = {
       drink: false,
       food: false
    } ;
  }
  handleDrink = () => {
   this.setState({ drink: true, food: false })
  };
  handleFood = () => {
     this.setState({ food: true, drink: false })
  }

  render() {
    const { drink, food } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={() => this.handleDrink()}>drink</button>
         <button onClick={() => this.handleFood()}>food </button>
         <div>
            {drink && console.log("goodbye world")}
            {food  && console.log('hello world')}
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: thank you i'm new to React and i was have a problem understanding  the state declaration  that's what i need exactly i understand now